# How to allow literal tab character in text input?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website. I can change the HTML/JS.

How do I let a tab press in `input type="text"` capture the tab character instead of advancing into the next input?

For example:

- HTML: `<input type="text"><input type="submit">`

If I type `a<tab>b`, then the input should have contents `a b` (not space, tab). The default is having `a` as contents, then tab changes focus to submit button.